# MongoDB: E11000 duplicate key error collection during Map Reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to count all last elements of an array. The array contains integers and may be empty.

The following Map Reduce example crashes on large collections (> 10 million entries) with a duplicate key error:

```js
var map = function() {
    if(this.path.length > 0) {
        emit(this.path.slice(-1)[0], 1);
    }
};
var reduce = function(id, values) {
    var sum = 0;
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        sum += value;
    });
    return sum;
};
db.input.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: 'output'})
```

Mongo version is 3.2 with WT engine. The example runs fine on smaller collections (e.g. ~500k entries)

Full error:

```
2016-02-25T19:20:09.078+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: map reduce failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: my_db.tmp.mr.input_10 index: _id_ dup key: { : 174.0 }",
    "code" : 11000
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
DBCollection.prototype.mapReduce@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1300:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: Does the `output` collection already exist when you run this? If so, you can specify the [`action`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#output-to-a-collection-with-an-action) to take to handle duplicates.

Comment: The output collection does not exist but maybe I can re-reduce documents with duplicate keys? I'll try that in the morning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the mapReduce example failed is because the last element of the array can either be an integer or an array itself. I'm not sure what the error message is trying to tell my though.

I found the reason thanks to Blakes Seven, who suggested the Aggregation Pipeline. Not only is it faster and less code, it also crashes with a clear and understandable error:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "insert for $out failed: { connectionId: 599, err: \"can't use an array for _id\", code: 2, n: 0, ok: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 16996
} : aggregate failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MongoDB 3.2 then mapReduce is completely the wrong tool for this anyway and you should instead be uning [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

MongoDB 3.2 inroduced [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to the aggregation framework which is basically the same as `.slice()`, and also the even better yet [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/), which with the latter can just return the last element of the array as a single value, just like you want:

```js
db.input.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "path.0": { "$exists": true } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$path", -1 ] },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$out": "output" }
])
```

So that is grouping ( [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) ) on the last element of the array and summing up the counts per each value of those elements just like you want to.

Additionally, using the initial query with [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter out empty arrays ( testing for the presence of the 0 index position means it must have some defined length ) is a lot more efficient than the brute force code test you were using. Arguable the mapReduce operation would benefit from the same "query" input to filter.

Then there is [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/), which is optional as the `.aggregate()` method unlike mapReduce can return instead a "cursor" for larger result sets. So you might not even need that unless you really want the output to go into another collection.

The main lesson here is "use the aggregate statement". Unlike mapReduce the operators all use native code and not interpretted JavaScript. The result is it runs faster, and **much** faster than the corresponding mapReduce.

---

Just for the record, your mapReduce is therefore more efficient ( but not as good as aggregate ) when written like this

```js
db.input.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this.path.slice(-1)[0],1);
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return Array.sum(values);
    },
    {
        "out": "output",
        "query": { "path.0": { "$exists": true } }
    }
)
```

And also for the record, the `"out"` in mapReduce **always** overwrites the collection unless you are explicitly setting the `"merge"` or `"reduce"` options.